# Invalid JSON Syntax and $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file *my.json* with the following content:

```
{   
    title: "My Title",
}
```

And, a jQuery snippet to read it:

```
var reading_file = $.getJSON('my.json', function (data) {
  alert('Success.');
}
```

The *alert()* inside the callback never gets called because there is an error in the JSON file i.e. `title` is not wrapped as a string, as in`"title"`.

When run on the browser (Chrome), this did not throw an error or any indication of something was wrong. To be specific, `my.json` was retrieved properly (status code: 200), although `reading_file.state()` is always `pending`.

My questions:

1. What is a good way to catch this type of error i.e. invalid JSON data / syntax?
2. Inside the `function (data) { alert ... }` callback, what does `this` refer to?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `this` refers to the AJAX request. `$.getJSON` is just a shortcut to using `$.ajax` in a certain way

Comment: And from the jQuery API docs, "As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason."

Comment: Why don't you try `$.getJSON("url", function () {}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown); });`

Comment: Thanks (+1), @Ian! Related to your other comment, I am wondering how you'd found out that `this` actually refers to the `ajaxSettings` object? Maybe my question is more basic than that: when I set a breakpoint on that `alert` line and investigate `this`, `this.constructor` returns a function that calls a native code.

Comment: Like I commented on the answer you accepted - I think I found it out from some StackOverflow question and/or inspecting it myself to figure it out. I'll check out `this.constructor` and see what it is. But if you try this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this));` inside the callback, you'll see the full `ajaxSettings` object that was actually used. I'll let you know if I find anything out about its constructor...

Comment: So if you do `alert({}.constructor);` you get the same thing as if you alert the `this.constructor`, which is what you'd expect since they're both object literals. Now, I don't know nearly enough about constructors or prototypes or blah blah blah to explain anything more to you about the `constructor` stuff :) Other things, maybe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown

You would use the error handler to catch the error. Something like

```
var reading_file = $.getJSON('my.json', function (data) {
  alert('Success.');
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Stop! Error time!");
});
```

**Update**

As mentioned by [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317927/ian), `this` in the *success* callback context is *not* an Ajax Event. It appears to be the configuration object passed to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: It should be more of a `-1/2`. `this` does not refer to an Ajax Event as you linked to. The callback is an Ajax Event. But inside of that callback, `this` refers to the `ajaxSettings` object that is passed to the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @Ian ah, I read the docs incorrectly then. It's not entirely obvious what they're referring to with *"This is an Ajax Event"*

Comment: Well, they aren't really clear where it's defined, so I think I've only learned that from reading it on SO and/or testing it myself to see. I tried to take back the downvote earlier but it has been too long without an edit or something